# "high security" software wants to turn my Windows PC into a single-tasking appliance

Tags: windows-7

I am running a fairly standard, recent install of Windows 7 Ultimate.  From time to time, I have to run an academic test-taking application.  This application:

- Appears to close **every** other application
- Takes over one monitor
- Blanks the other monitor

After I exit the test:

- There are no icons on my desktop
- The taskbar is gone

There's nothing for me to do but hit `Ctrl+ALt+Delete`, log out, and log back in again.  Most inconvenient!

How can I tame this monster?

Comment: I wonder if running it in a VM would be overkill

Comment: @Pitarou - Report the problem to the school.  If you have to stretch the truth, say the program makes your system unstable, request alternatives.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Another good suggestion.  Unfortunately, this software refuses to run if it detects that it's running on a VM.

Comment: @Ramhound That's an excellent idea.  Unfortunately, my school doesn't treat distance learning students like human beings, but I'll give it a try all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the application is killing explorer.

If you restart explorer, the taskbar & desktop icons should re-appear.

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete
2. Click Start Task Manager
3. Click New Task
4. Type `Explorer`
5. Press OK

Comment: Thanks.  That's useful.  How do I restart the Taskbar?

Comment: Explorer **is** the task bar.

Comment: When `Explorer.exe` runs, if there are no other instances running, then it will show the taskbar and desktop icons. If there are other instances, it will open a folder window.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with SLaks answer that Explorer is getting killed, however you can create a simple batch file that will restart explorer for you. In a file ending with `.bat` put just these two lines.

```
C:\Path\To\Test\Program\NameOfTestTakingProgram.exe
explorer.exe
```

This will wait till the test taking program exits then automatically restart explorer.

Comment: Except that the program is likely to kill the batch file too.

Comment: @SLaks Did not think of that.

Comment: It's worth a try.  Thanks for the suggestion.